# swagger-typescript-api - how can i remove type of request after request name?

Tags: typescript, api, types, swagger, generate

I would like to generate types from a Swagger file without adding a request type after the request name.

For example:
When I have endpoint /assortment and request type: POST. I get Api.assortmentCreate() method in api client.

I want to delete the name "create" because it might be something else.

Does anyone know how to help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

swagger-typescript-api is template driven. It uses Eta templates. You can supply your own template to override the default templates. You can do this by creating a local `templates` directory and dropping your replacement templates in there. For example I wanted to change request names from the `routeCreate` format to `postRoute`, So I dropped the following `route-name.eta` template into `templates`.

```
<%
const { routeInfo, utils } = it;
const {
  operationId,
  method,
  route,
  moduleName,
  responsesTypes,
  description,
  tags,
  summary,
  pathArgs,
} = routeInfo;
const { _, fmtToJSDocLine, require } = utils;

const methodAliases = {
  get: (suffix) => _.camelCase(`get${suffix}`),
  post: (suffix) => _.camelCase(`post${suffix}`),
  put: (suffix) => _.camelCase(`put${suffix}`),
  patch: (suffix) => _.camelCase(`patch${suffix}`),
  delete: (suffix) => _.camelCase(`delete${suffix}`),
};

const createCustomOperationId = (method, route, moduleName) => {
    console.log(`=== ${method} ${route}`);
  const hasPathInserts = /\{(\w){1,}\}/g.test(route);
  const splitedRouteBySlash = _.compact(_.replace(route, /\{(\w){1,}\}/g, "").split("/"));
  const routeParts = (splitedRouteBySlash.length > 1
    ? splitedRouteBySlash.splice(1)
    : splitedRouteBySlash
  ).join("_");
  const suffix = route.indexOf('{scope}') < 0 ? '' : '_scope';
  return methodAliases[method]
    ? methodAliases[method](suffix)
    : _.camelCase(_.lowerCase(method) + "_" + [moduleName].join("_")) || "index";
};

if (operationId)
  return _.camelCase(operationId);
if (route === "/")
  return _.camelCase(`${_.lowerCase(method)}Root`);

return createCustomOperationId(method, route, moduleName);
%>
```